# C# Error when reading csv file: “make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size”

Tags: c#, csv

I am new to C# and can't figure out where I have gone wrong, I am trying to import a CSV file with three numbers, (with 6 decimal places) on each row (roughly 20,000 rows) and I get the following error

> ("make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size")

when I try and open a CSV file using the code below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string file_input = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file_input));
    List<decimal> points = new List<decimal>();
    string[] p = new string[2];

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        p[0] = values[0];
        p[1] = values[1];       //error occurs here
        p[2] = values[2];

        points.AddRange(p);
    }
    comboBox1.Items.Add(points);

}
```

Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: put a break point on `Split` see if you get atleast 3 array elements after split. Probably you have an empty line or something which is not returning 3 elements after split

Comment: string[] p = new string[2]; Shouldn't that be a 3?

Comment: yes! thank you, is it possible to read the file into a decimal format without having to convert it?

Comment: No.  But you've got the text pieces already, so it's easy:  `Convert.ToDecimal(p[0].Trim());`.

Comment: Brilliant! one more question, how do i add the p list to the points list so it would be ((123.456, 123.456, 123.456),(789.123, 789.123, 789123).....)?